reported speech unreal past
After a number of expressions such as : if only, would rather, wish and so on we use past tense to describe things in the present. In reported speech they do not backshift, "I would rather you did it" has the same form when reported "He said he would rather you did it". Now my question. What if we have more than one clause after those expressions. For instance "I would rather you did it when she comes" or I would rather do it because she's pretty. As I understand the first clause always is the same we do not backshift it even if something is no longer true after expressions which I mentioned. What about the second clause? You can use examples that I presented.

We don't have to use past tense. "I would rather you do it" is a perfectly good alternative to "I would rather you did it". But if there's another clause containing a verb, both verbs should match: Either "I would rather you do it when she comes"  OR "I would rather you did it when she came" .

...I see you asked about this before: reporting time clauses in the past and future, but no-one there seems to have made the point in my first comment.

I wish you had done it

We don't have to use past tense for the "hypothetical" clause describing some preferred alternative. "I would rather you do it" is a perfectly good alternative to "I would rather you did it".
But if there's an additional clause containing a verb within that alternative, both verbs should match: "I would rather you do it when she comes" OR "I would rather you did it when she came".
But note that if even the possibility of that alternative happening has now passed, it's normally "I would rather you had done it when she came" (we don't usually repeat the Past Perfect as "...when she had come").
